# Reference trouble with wxPython FileDialog if and else statements

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having some trouble when using if and else statements where I'm using multiple wx.FileDialog statements to change the file type I'm allowing the user to select based on what radio button is selected.  So the problem is I keep getting an UnboundLocalError that my local variable assigned to the FileDialog statement referenced before assignment.  Here is my code:

```
def OnOpen(self, e):
if self.radioButton1.GetValue():
   opendialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", "", "", "*.txt", wx.MULTIPLE)
if self.radioButton2.GetValue():
   opendialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", "", "", "*.csv", wx.MULTIPLE)
else:
   selectdialog = wx.MessageDialog(self,"Select process", "Warn", wx.OK)
   selectdialog.ShowModal()
   selectdialog.Destroy()
if opendialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
   #More code to file path information
```

Comment: Do you mean "elif self.radioButton2..."?

Comment: @acattle,  I didn't mean that but I should have.  I think that would have fixed my problem too.  Thanks for saying that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're falling into the second "if" statement's "else" condition without opendialog ever being defined. You'll need to make sure it's initialized somehow in every case, not just in two of the three. Otherwise that last "if" statement will fail. So make sure you add

```
opendialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", "", "", "*.csv", wx.MULTIPLE)
```

to the end of the second "if" statement and it will work in all cases.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  The second 'if' statement already has the wx.FileDialog.  Did you mean the "else" statement?  Problem with that is I want to show the MessageDialog on the else, not the wx.FileDialog.  Maybe you meant the opendialog.ShowModal if statement?  That one I need to add the code to get the file path information.  I tried repeating that last if statement (opendialog.ShowModal() but the else statement still runs when I select radiobutton1 for some reason.

Comment: The second "if" statement only instantiates the opendialog in the first part, not the second part (i.e. the else). So if BOTH the first "if" and the first part of the second "if" never run, then the 3rd "if" will fail because opendialog is not defined.

Comment: As @acattle stated, adding elif to the second if seems to fix the problem only if I add the if opendialog.ShowModal() to both if and elif statements